# Downloading 22.04 iso

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to download the latest Ubuntu for my desktop but when I try to download the iso it says " Load failed , not enough room on your harddrive". I have a 500G drive and a 4.7 G flashdrive and DVD but I can't free up enough room on my desktop to download the iso. Is there a way I can directly download it to the flashdrive or DVD?

Comment: Downloading the ISO directly to DVD or flashdrive (USB) won't make them bootable DVD or USB. Copying the ISO file into the DVD or USB wont work either. You have to first download the ISO into the hard disk of your computer and then use a special software to "burn" or create the DVD or USB to make them bootable. You can buy or borrow a second (and bigger) USB drive and directly download the ISO file into it.

Comment: @user68186 OP seems to have very less free space left in the home folder.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I edited my comment.

Comment: Try the commands `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove -y` to free up some space in the hard drive.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It is not clear OP is using Ubuntu (or any Linux distro).

Comment: If you have previously installed Ubuntu, then you *already know* that that LiveUSB must be created; that you simply cannot download or copy it onto the USB. This suggests that you might not be using Ubuntu yet, in which case the installer will *certainly* reformat your hard drive, deleting everything. Everything! Back it up onto some other storage if you don't want it lost forever.

Comment: It's possible for you to download an ISO to one thumb-drive (*as a data drive; as it's only a storage location; my downloads are to network shares & never the small drive I have the system installed to; it'd never fit there*), but you cannot install from where its downloaded to. You still need to write the ISO to a media for installation; so whilst downloading it to a different storage media is for sure possible, you still need to write/burn it to media later.  You can boot off an ISO on disk if downloaded to the machine you want to use it on, but that involves a lot of intricate setup.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not able to free some space up from your hard drive and you have both, a DVD and a thumbdrive available, you can easily solve (temporarily) the problem by downloading the ISO to either your USB flash drive or DVD, then use some of the widely available software to burn the image to the other portable device, for example:

#1. Connect the USB flash drive **AND** insert the DVD

#2. Download the ISO to your USB

#3. Use a burning software and select the ISO in the USB as source

#4. Burn the image to the DVD

#5. Remove USB and boot from DVD